# Display interception and support non-latin or complex scripting language in Andorid

Tags: android, unicode, fonts

I am planning to do an Android application to support non-Latin complex scripting language in Android. Unicode support is already there in the Android but some Unicode text rendering has issues that make the languages untidy.

Main idea is to identify the language and perform rules based on the identified language. So it will be:

- Define rules and store them
- Identify language
- Apply rules

Some languages have NZWJ (non zero width joining) rules that behave in differently like left, right, both left and right, top, both top and left etc.

My questions are:

- Is there are a proper/documented resources to get this done? (best text book to be referred etc.)
- What will be the affects in browser and other applications that use the same language and how this can be applied to those applications ?
- What are the changes has to be done to fonts or standards to be followed ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an old question, but I see you are still an active member. Would you consider either answering this question in more detail with your own solution or trying to answer my question I recently posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539237/supporting-complex-text-layout-with-opentype-fonts-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thesis done for a master course is available at [this link](http://sdsu-dspace.calstate.edu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10211.10/1032/Bhasin_Dhruv.pdf?sequence=1). The project has done to support non-Latin language using Devanagiri font script as a model.

Most parts of the question is answered in the thesis.